# CSS - set image to a hight and keep its ratio when scaling

Tags: css

I have a demo [here](https://codepen.io/ttmt/pen/XWNzpBa)

Its really simple but I'm stuck,

I have an image that it 4:3, I need to keep that ratio.

I want the image to start at 400px in height but then keep it's ratio when the window is resized

I have this that I thought would keep the ratio, but can't get it to work

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
padding-top: 56.25%;
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?
do you want to have image scale with parent element in height and keep accept ratio of 4:3

Comment: You could investigate object -fit or background-image contain.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shashank-shantaram-anuja-padwal/pen/XWNzRxb
here is the solution to your problem :)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, so i make it a comment. I would go for a flex layout , a media querie to reset image on top or below the card on small résolution and use a bit of js to reset image's width. Also object-ifit can be used to avoid img distortion . fork of your pen revisited : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BaQmdBN

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what your problem is, but you can simply set `height` to `100%` (also for any wrappers in between the image and the element whose height it should take)  and define `width: auto;`:

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 400px;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}

.image img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/cc4" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">

  </div>
</div>
```